# Why Can't Collection Generic Type be Extended

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have a utility method that its goal is to convert a `Collection` into a `Map`. However, when I try to use generics, it gives a compilation error and was wondering how I can fix it:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> convertCollectionToMap(Collection<V extends ListToMapConvertable<K, V>> sourceList) {
    Map<K, V> newMap = new HashMap<K, V>();
    for (V item : sourceList) {
        newMap.put(item.getKey(item), item);
    }

    return newMap;
} 

public interface ListToMapConvertable<K, V> {
    public K getKey(V item);
}
```

Instead, I am getting `Incorrect number of arguments for type Collection<E>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <V, ListToMapConvertable>` compilation error. I don't understand the issue as `V` is just **extending** `ListToMapConverable`. So why does it claim that I am using two arguments -- `<V, ListToMapConvertable>`? And how do I get around this?

Comment: You can't put a generic bound `extends ...` there.  You need to place it on the generic parameter declaration (i.e. the initial `<K, V>`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The upper-bound should be specified in the declaration of the type, not in the declaration of the parameter :

```
public static <K, V extends ListToMapConvertable<K, V>> Map<K, V> convertCollectionToMap(Collection<V> sourceList) {
     ....
}
```

As a side note, note also that the diamond operator (available since Java 7) allows to not repeat the generic type in the instantiated object declaration.
So this is enough :

```
Map<K, V> newMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: I was not aware of the capability of the diamond operator in Java 7+ to understand the parameterized value defined in the reference and not requiring them in the instantiation. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: You are welcome :) But I am not sure that your actual code will produce the expected result. `ListToMapConvertable` declaration and `convertCollectionToMap()` are not consistent between. According to how `ListToMapConvertable` is defined, `V` is distinct of the `ListToMapConvertable` type. While `item.getKey(item)`  considers that  `ListToMapConvertable` and the parameter of `getKey()` rely on the same type.